# Do nextjs server actions replace the need for edge functions or a traditional backend?

Tags: next.js, architecture, serverless, serverside-javascript, edge-function

At first glance it seems that [NextJS server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations) are similarly implemented to edge functions in serverless computing. They can do many things including run code on the server, it's hard for me to understand their true purpose and how they differentiate themselves from other server side implementations.

I'm curious as to their limitations and how they are different from traditional server side code, for example one of the use cases from vercel is to fetch data for the user.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't expect anyone to write a book in Stackoverflow. If you are serious about understanding Next.js follow this tutorial. https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app. It's an investment of a few hours, which you have do make yourself. Have fun and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you have to learn the basics of Next.js. I assume you  already know React. Use the Framework and ask again for specific information or coding hints.

Good starting points are the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs) and [this excellent tutorial (!)](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app).